# Including phpinfo() function

Tags: php

When we upload a PHP file which include `phpinfo()` function, to a free web hosting site how it cause security problems for me ? Can end users get information about `PHP` in my computer ?

Comment: It won't return any information about your computer. It runs on the server, and returns information about the server's configuration.

Answer (score 0):

While the end users cannot get information about your computer (since it's not running the script) they will get lots of information about the server that the script is running on.

This does not generally create security problems for you, but it might create security problems for the owner of that server (ie; the free hosting site you put it on) because it might expose that they have unsafe libraries installed or use versions with known exploits something like that.

**EDIT**

However, keep in mind that if the machine hosting your code is compromised by an attacker this will also have consequences for your application. While the security exploits (if any) should be fixed by your hosting provider, if they don't, then attackers might be able to gain access to your code and data as well.

Comment: It's not really true that the risk is all to the hosting provider: firstly, any risk to the host is a risk to the users of that host; secondly, the configuration may be customised by/for a particular user.

Comment: Hm, fair point. I´ll update the answer.